# DiffUtil.Callback not working as expected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils, android-listadapter

I am using DiffUtil.ItemCallback along with ListAdapter to update RecyclerView.

It's working pretty well but there is something that bothering me with it's behaviour.

According to the documentation, the `areContentsTheSame` method should be called only if `areItemsTheSame` returns `true`.

From the documentation:

> This method is called only if areItemsTheSame(int, int) returns true for these items.

However, in my case when updating the list with a new list, like this:

```
adapter.submitList(items.toMutableList())
```

The DiffUtil.ItemCallback do triggered but even when `areItemsTheSame` returns `true` it wont call `areContentTheSame` right away (as expected?) but instead, `areItemsTheSame` called again and again on different pair of objects, (I've used debugger with breakpoints there).
After `areItemsTheSame` called a few times and return true, finally it do calls `areContentTheSame` and sometimes, I see that the objects that delivered to `areContentTheSame` actually not the same!! and has different id!! this means that `areContentTheSame` shouldn't even called on these pair!!

This is how my DiffUtilCallback is implemented:

```
class AppDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item?>() {

override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean {
    Timber.i("areItemsTheSame: called..")
    if (oldItem.getItemType() == newItem.getItemType()) {
        Timber.i("areItemsTheSame: done true..")
        return true
    }
    Timber.w("areItemsTheSame: done false..")
    return false
}

override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean {
    Timber.i("areContentsTheSame: called")
    if(oldItem.getItemType() != newItem.getItemType()){
        Timber.w("areContentsTheSame: itemsNotTheSame WTF???}")
        return false
    }

    return when (oldItem.getItemType()) {
        Item.HEADER -> checkHeaderContent(oldItem = oldItem as ItemHeader, newItem = newItem as ItemHeader)
        Item.ITEM_ACTION -> checkItemContent(oldItem = oldItem as ItemAction, newItem = newItem as ItemAction)
        else -> false
    }
}

   private fun checkHeaderContent(oldItem: ItemHeader, newItem: 
     ItemHeader): Boolean {
         val itemContentTheSame = oldItem.date.toDate().time == 
         newItem.date.toDate().time
         return itemContentTheSame
   }

   private fun checkItemContent(oldItem: ItemAction, newItem: ItemAction): Boolean {
        val itemContentTheSame = oldItem.action == newItem.action
        return itemContentTheSame
   }
}
```

In addition, when running this, in the logcat I see many calls to `areItemsTheSame` with `true` but very few `areContentTheSame`

Is this an expected behaviour?